# Create batch File to run one time and exit comand prompt window

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, batch-file

This is the command line i want to run on my windows xp machine

```
arp -s 192.168.1.1 11-22-33-44-11-22
```

I tried ti make code like this into arp.bat

```
arp -s 192.168.1.1 11-22-33-44-11-22
exit
```

When i double click on it . It keep window command prompt open and command repeat over and over

**UPDATED MY QUESTION :** How can i make it run one time only and exit the command prompt after finish the execute ?

Or

If there anyway to make this command

```
arp -s 192.168.1.1 11-22-33-44-11-22
```

run when windows start

Or

If there any way to make this file run one time using different method than regular batch file in windows xp

Comment: can you include the output?

Comment: the output is black screen with echo off  in batch file , with echo on in batch file the output is command execute in loop never quit

Comment: does that happen from command line too outside of batch file? and when you say a loop, do you mean the output keeps coming, (in which case what output appears), or do you mean the command keeps executing (rather hard to believe).  I can't test the command at the moment, and you still haven't shown the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i found the problem

when i created the batch i saved under the name **arp.bat** this is was the problem the command keep repeating itself never quit

I renamed the arp.bat to batch.bat or any name not related with arp word and it works well with no problem